# Delaunay triangulatioin vertex insertion

Tags: delaunay

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWkJt.png)
this is the code for inserting a vertex in Delaunay

knowing persons pls explain this pseudocode

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The text you cite looks like it may have come from "Delaunay Mesh Generation" by Cheng, Dey, and Shewchuk (who has contributed greatly to software community through his work on the Delaunay).

The discussion is a bit terse and I can see where you might find it hard to follow.  I used it as a starting point for my own Delaunay implementation, but ended up referring to other sources. I wrote up some discussion of what I did, and you may find some helpful information in http://gwlucastrig.github.io/Tinfour/doc/TinfourAlgorithmsAndDataElements.pdf

If you want to see a Java-based implementation of the algorithm, you can download the source code from the Tinfour project, find the IncrementalTin.java class and look at the insert() method.  However, Tinfour is intended to be production-grade code rather than instructive, and the code is complicated a bit by the inclusion of optimizations.  You may visit Tinfour at https://github.com/gwlucastrig/Tinfour